# Problem with jshell on intellij IDEA on the terminal

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jshell

I have a problem with jshell on intellij IDEA on the terminal for type curly braces, when I select alt gr + shift and the brackets, the terminal don't create a curly brackets but say, press tab again to see all possible complections, I have an italian keybord, How I can resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, please provide more details, especially operating system.
For instance open Remote Desktop connections in Windows are known to modify / swallow AltGr key inputs.

Comment: I have the same problem. Windows 10, openjdk 15, italian keyboard. Using traditional CMD prompt